Postrgresql Logical replication causing very high buildup of log files even though replication slots are active [ AWS RDS postgresql 16.1]
I have two rds instances and have set up logical replication between them [ publisher subscriber]. for the 3-4 days everything was working fine wal files were getting cleared but suddenly when the traffic on the source db increased wal files were not getting transmitted.
Weird part was only one table was experiencing high amount of inserts for longer duration, but it caused the wall build up for all other replication slots also, to more than 50 GB.
pub_das_sub_site_kpis | 110 GB
pub_subscriber_report | 50 GB
pub_line_site_location | 90 GB
...

Only the first table das_sub_site_kpis was getting inserts and the weirdest part is line_site_location table was empty
select count(*) from line_site_location

count(*)
---------
   0

Has anyone faced the same issue before?
Thanks a lot!

You probably got long-running transactions.
